# How do I prove and expand Bayesian Networks?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian-network

Attempting to understand Exercise 20 (pdf page 44) in the paper: (Warning: large paper; small exercise)

[Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/090310.pdf)

> The party animal problem corresponds to the network in g(3.14). The boss is angry and the worker has a headache - what is the probability  the worker has been to a party?
>
> When set to 1 the statements are true: P = Been to Party, H = Got a Headache, D = Demotivated at work, U = Underperform at work, A =Boss Angry. Shaded variables (A, H) are observed in the true state.
>
> $\begin{matrix} & & D \\ & & \downarrow \\ P & \rightarrow & U \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ (H) & & (A)\end{matrix} $

I would like to solve the following:

- Prove that p(P|H,A ) = a*p(P,H,A) where a is a constant.
- Expand p(P, H, A) by marginalizing over the variables U and D.
- how to compute 'a'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: $p(P\mid H, A) = \left(\dfrac{1}{p(H,A)}\right) p(P,H,A)$

Comment: @graham-kemp: thank you for the edit. So, does this answers the first and last question? where a = 1/p(H,A) ? Any ideas on expanding? Thank You for your time.

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate because, after 3+ years, it seems the most constructive disposition.  There could be an argument that the OP wants some resolution of the Question that does not depend on the missing information noted in the linked duplicate, but it appears the OP has long ago abandoned the problem and lost interest in any finer details.

Comment: @hardmath: that is true, but others may not...let's do the vote thing...